# Inserting Multiple Rows into a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I've written the code below and keep getting an error for incorrect syntax

It said at line 10 near the `,` - so this line:

```
values(1, 'Stolz', 'Ted', 25000, NULL), )
```

If I only try to insert the first row of data it works fine, it's when I try to do multiple. Am I missing something really simple?

```
Drop Table #TPerson

CREATE TABLE #TPerson 
(
    personid int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(50) NULL,
    firstname varchar(50) NULL,
    salary money NULL,
    managerid int NULL
);

Insert Into #TPerson(Personid, lastname, firstname, salary, managerid)
values (1, 'Stolz', 'Ted', 25000, NULL),
       (2, 'Boswell', 'Nancy', 23000, 1),
       (3, 'Hargett', 'Vincent', 22000, 1),
       (4, 'Weekley', 'Kevin', 22000, 3),
       (5, 'Metts', 'Geraldine', 22000, 2),
       (6, 'McBride', 'Jeffrey', 21000, 2),
       (7, 'Xiong', 'Jay', 20000, 3)
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? It can be some DBMS-related syntax issue. At least your code snippet works perfectly in MS SQL Server.

Comment: Which dbms product are you using? Not all of them support that construction. (The following feature outside Core SQL-2003 is used: F641, "Row and table constructors", according to the SQL Validator, http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x.)

Comment: What **VERSION** of SQL Server are you running this against? What is the output of `SELECT @@VERSION` for your server? This syntax with multiple tuples was introduced in SQL Server **2008** - if you have an earlier version, you cannot use this syntax

Comment: I thought I had 2008 (so it says anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this:

```
Insert Into #TPerson(Personid,lastname,firstname,salary,managerid)
select 1,'Stolz','Ted',25000,NULL
union all select 2,'Boswell','Nancy',23000,1
union all select 3,'Hargett','Vincent',22000,1
union all select 4,'Weekley','Kevin',22000,3
union all select 5,'Metts','Geraldine',22000,2
union all select 6,'McBride','Jeffrey',21000,2
union all select 7,'Xiong','Jay',20000,3
```